# jasper report path for jsf web application on shared tomcat hosting

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, tomcat, jasper-reports

My application is in JSF  with Jasper Report. It works perfectly on my local machine. But when I am uploading .WAR file online on **"shared tomcat server"** the problem with jasper report starts

I am trying to access the jasper report from folder **Web Pages (/report/design/report1.jasper)**  but report not found.

1. This is my application path for working

   http://myDomainName.com/Trial1/
2. And after calling to jasper report it goes to following URL (from this form jasperReport.xhtml calling jasper report)

   http://myDomainName.com/Trial1/faces/jasperReport.xhtml
3. My Reports located at path is

   private final String COMPILE_DIR = "/report/design/";
4. code is

**AbstractReportBean.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.BaseHttpServlet;
import com.bari.report.util.ReportConfigUtil;


public abstract class AbstractReportBean {

public enum ExportOption {

    PDF, HTML, EXCEL, RTF
}
private ExportOption exportOption;
private final String COMPILE_DIR = "/report/design/";
private String message;

public AbstractReportBean() {
    super();
    setExportOption(ExportOption.PDF);
}

protected void prepareReport() throws JRException, IOException {
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    ServletContext context = (ServletContext) externalContext.getContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

    ReportConfigUtil.compileReport(context, getCompileDir(), getCompileFileName());

    File reportFile = new File(ReportConfigUtil.getJasperFilePath(context, getCompileDir(), getCompileFileName() + ".jasper"));

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = Database.getConnection();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    JasperPrint jasperPrint = ReportConfigUtil.fillReport(reportFile, getReportParameters(), conn);

    if (getExportOption().equals(ExportOption.HTML)) {
        ReportConfigUtil.exportReportAsHtml(jasperPrint, response.getWriter());
    } else if (getExportOption().equals(ExportOption.EXCEL)) {
        ReportConfigUtil.exportReportAsExcel(jasperPrint, response.getWriter());
    } else {
        request.getSession().setAttribute(BaseHttpServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, jasperPrint);
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/servlets/report/" + getExportOption());
    }

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}

public ExportOption getExportOption() {
    return exportOption;
}

public void setExportOption(ExportOption exportOption) {
    this.exportOption = exportOption;
}

protected Map<String, Object> getReportParameters() {
    return new HashMap<String, Object>();
}

protected String getCompileDir() {
    return COMPILE_DIR;
}

protected abstract String getCompileFileName();

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

}

//--------------------------------------------------

**ReportConfigUtil.java**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Map;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHtmlExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHtmlExporterParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporterParameter;

public class ReportConfigUtil {

/**
 * PRIVATE METHODS
 */
private static void setCompileTempDir(ServletContext context, String uri) {
    System.setProperty("jasper.reports.compile.temp", context.getRealPath(uri));
}

/**
 * PUBLIC METHODS
 */
public static boolean compileReport(ServletContext context, String compileDir, String filename) throws JRException {
    String jasperFileName = context.getRealPath(compileDir + filename + ".jasper");
    File jasperFile = new File(jasperFileName);

    if (jasperFile.exists()) {
        return true; // jasper file already exists, do not compile again
    }
    try {
        // jasper file has not been constructed yet, so compile the xml file
        setCompileTempDir(context, compileDir);

        String xmlFileName = jasperFileName.substring(0, jasperFileName.indexOf(".jasper")) + ".jrxml";
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(xmlFileName);

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public static JasperPrint fillReport(File reportFile, Map<String, Object> parameters, Connection conn) throws JRException {
    parameters.put("BaseDir", reportFile.getParentFile());

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportFile.getPath(), parameters, conn);

    return jasperPrint;
}

public static String getJasperFilePath(ServletContext context, String compileDir, String jasperFile) {
    return context.getRealPath(compileDir + jasperFile);
}

private static void exportReport(JRAbstractExporter exporter, JasperPrint jasperPrint, PrintWriter out) throws JRException {
    try{
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_WRITER, out);

    exporter.exportReport();
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();e.getMessage();}
}

public static void exportReportAsHtml(JasperPrint jasperPrint, PrintWriter out) throws JRException {
    JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_WRITER, out);
    exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "ISO-8859-9");

    exportReport(exporter, jasperPrint, out);
}

public static void exportReportAsExcel(JasperPrint jasperPrint, PrintWriter out) throws JRException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStream outputfile = new FileOutputStream(new File("d:/JasperReport1.xls"));
    // coding For Excel:
    JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.exportReport();
    outputfile.write(output.toByteArray());
}
```

}

Comment: Still haven't stated the problem

Comment: @kolossus thanks for reply.. my problem is jasper report dosent run on when .war file uploaded to tomcat server. I think **path of jasper report file not found**.